# "Make" command gave error while trying to compile AP drivers for MT7601U on raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, hardware, driver, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, wireless-adapter

i have a wifi adapter which has MT7601U chipset in it, but the driver in linux kernel for this chipset doesn't support AP mode, so i was trying to install the AP driver from this github page:
https://github.com/Anthony96922/mt7601u-ap

I was following the instructions, but when i tried using the "make" command, it gave me an error:

```
pi4@raspberrypi:~ $ git clone https://github.com/Anthony96922/mt7601u-ap
Cloning into 'mt7601u-ap'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3365, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2231/2231), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (569/569), done.
remote: Total 3365 (delta 1765), reused 1892 (delta 1638), pack-reused 1134
Receiving objects: 100% (3365/3365), 4.80 MiB | 58.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2375/2375), done.
pi4@raspberrypi:~ $ cd mt7601u-ap
pi4@raspberrypi:~/mt7601u-ap $ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi4/mt7601u-ap/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi4/mt7601u-ap/tools'
/home/pi4/mt7601u-ap/tools/bin2h
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.76-v8+/build M=/home/pi4/mt7601u-ap/os/linux modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.15.76-v8+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:73: LINUX] Error 2
```

Comment: You appear to be following an 8 year old post for an obsolete 32bit OS (at least using obsolete concepts like modprobe) on a 64bit OS.

Comment: Did you install the kernel source packages?

Comment: kernel source packages?

Comment: @Milliways then where can i get a modern AP driver for MT7601U?